# .Net Core: Validate Anti Forgery Token with Ionic front end

Tags: ionic-framework, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, antiforgerytoken

I have looked all over and have found similar solutions, but nothing that matches exactly what I'm working on.

We have a .net core MVC website with an API Controller for handling requests from an ionic mobile app which we are also developing.

In most cases, adding `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to the API controller actions works. I have gone through the process of generating the token, passing it to Ionic, and storing it in the request headers for validation.

Here is the code I am using to fetch and store the token:

```
static XSRF_TOKEN_KEY: string = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
static XSRF_TOKEN_NAME_KEY: string = "X-XSRF-TOKEN-NAME";

constructor(){}

static getXsrfToken(http: HTTP) : {tokenName: string, token: string} {
    let tokenName: string = window.sessionStorage.getItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_NAME_KEY);
    let token: string = window.sessionStorage.getItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_KEY);
    if(!tokenName || !token){
        this.fetchXsrfToken(http);
        tokenName= window.sessionStorage.getItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_NAME_KEY);
        token = window.sessionStorage.getItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_KEY);
    }
    return {
        tokenName: tokenName,
        token: token
    };
}

private static setXsrfToken({ token, tokenName }: { token: string, tokenName: string }) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_KEY, token);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_NAME_KEY, tokenName);
}

private static fetchXsrfToken(http: HTTP) {
    let token: string = window.sessionStorage.getItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_KEY);
    let tokenName: string = window.sessionStorage.getItem(ValidationManager.XSRF_TOKEN_NAME_KEY);

    if (!token || !tokenName) {
        let apiUrl: string = AppConfig.apiUrl + "/GetAntiforgeryToken";
        http.get(apiUrl, {}, {})
            .then(r => this.setXsrfToken(JSON.parse(r.data)))
            .catch(r => console.error("Could not fetch XSRFTOKEN", r));
    } else {
        this.setXsrfToken({ token: token, tokenName: tokenName });
    }
}
```

Here is the action in my controller that serves anti forgery tokens:

```
[HttpGet]
public override IActionResult GetAntiforgeryToken()
{
    var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
    return new ObjectResult(new
    {
        token = tokens.RequestToken,
        tokenName = tokens.HeaderName
    });
    }
```

I set the headers of the http plugin by calling this function from the view's associated typescript file:

```
initializeHttp() {
    let token = ValidationManager.getXsrfToken(this.http);
    this.http.setHeader(token.tokenName, token.token);
    console.log("Http Initialized: ", token);
}
```

then any request I make with the http plugin is validated properly in the controller's action:

```
this.http.post(apiUrl, {}, {}).then(response => {
   that.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
});
```

**Up to this point, everything works great.** The problem arises when I try to use `XmlHttpRequest` to for a POST instead of the built-in http plugin:

```
let file = {
    name: e.srcElement.files[0].name,
    file: e.srcElement.files[0],
  };

  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file.file);

  let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', apiUrl, true);
  console.log("setting request header: ", tokenVal); //verify that tokenVal is correct
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", tokenVal);
  xhr.send(formData);
```

If I remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute from the controller's action, the file is posted properly. However, nothing I have tried has worked with the attribute being included.

I believe the issue has something to do with the validation tokens being added to a cookie automatically by Ionic, and the cookie is passed along with the request from the http plugin. However, `XMLHttpRequest` does not pass the cookie along (and is unable to do so?).

I have read up on the subject quite a bit over the past few days but I admit that this validation is still mostly a black box to me. **Is there a way to validate the request in my action using only the token which is passed up in the header?**

The reason I am running into this problem is that I need to upload a file, which I was unable to do using the http plugin. There are solutions for uploading images using Ionic's `file-transfer` plugin, but it has been deprecated and the release notes suggest using `XmlHttpRequest` instead.

**Other things I have tried:**

- I have found solutions for .net standard which use `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery` for custom validation on the server, but this namespace is not included in .net core and I could not find an equivalent.
- I tried many different ways to post the file using the http plugin (since it has no issues validating the antiForgery token). Everything I tried resulted in the action being hit but the file being posted was always `null`. A solution which uploads a file using the http plugin would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it that I was able to spend two full days on this problem, but as soon as I post a question about it, I find the answer? Sometimes I think the internet gods are just messing with me.

As it turns out, the native http plugin has an `uploadFile()` function that I never saw mentioned anywhere else. Here's what the solution does:

1. Use the `fileChooser` plugin to select a file from the phone's storage
2. Use the `filePath` plugin to resolve the native filesystem path of the image.
3. Use `http.uploadFile()` instead of `http.post()`

This works because as mentioned above, I was able to properly set the validation token in the http plugin's header to be accepted by the controller.

And here is the code:

```
let apiUrl: string = AppConfig.apiUrl + "/UploadImage/";
this.fileChooser.open().then(
  uri => {
    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then(resolvedPath => {
      loader.present();
      this.http.uploadFile(apiUrl,{ },{ },resolvedPath, "image")
      .then(result => {
        loader.dismiss();
        toastOptions.message = "File uploaded successfully!";
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create(toastOptions);
        toast.present();
        let json = JSON.parse(result.data);
        this.event.imageUrl = json.imgUrl;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        loader.dismiss();
        toastOptions.message = "Error uploading file";
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create(toastOptions);
        toast.present();
      });
    });
  }
).catch(
  e => console.log(e)
);
```